# Nullpointer to SurfaceHolder Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, deprecated, live-wallpaper, surfaceholder

Hey guys I am having this error with my live wallpaper. For some reason when I try to set the surface type i get a NullPointerException error. I am not sure whats going on there. Thanks in advance.

Error seems to be in the **SeType()** method.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MyWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {
    private Handler handler = null;

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return this.handler;
    }

    public WallpaperService.Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new MovieLiveWallpeperEngine();
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler paramHandler) {
        this.handler = paramHandler;
    }

    public class MovieLiveWallpeperEngine extends WallpaperService.Engine {
        private static final String TAG = "MovieLiveWallpeperEngine";
        public SurfaceHolder hold;
        private Camera mCamera = null;

        public MovieLiveWallpeperEngine() {
            super();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder paramSurfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(paramSurfaceHolder);
            this.hold = new MyWallpaperService.VideoSurfaceHolder(getSurfaceHolder());
            this.hold.setType(3);
        }

        public void onDesiredSizeChanged(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            if (this.mCamera != null) {
                this.mCamera.stopPreview();
                this.mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                this.mCamera.release();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        public void onOrientationChanged(int paramInt) {
        }

        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean paramBoolean) {
            if (paramBoolean)
                startVideo();
            while (true) {
                //return;
                stopVideo();
            }
        }

        public void setDisplayOrientation(Camera paramCamera, int paramInt) {
            try {
                Class localClass = paramCamera.getClass();
                Class[] arrayOfClass = new Class[1];
                arrayOfClass[0] = Integer.TYPE;
                Method localMethod = localClass.getMethod(
                        "setDisplayOrientation", arrayOfClass);
                if (localMethod != null) {
                    Object[] arrayOfObject = new Object[1];
                    arrayOfObject[0] = Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
                    localMethod.invoke(paramCamera, arrayOfObject);
                }
                label58: return;
            } catch (Exception localException) {
                //break;
            }
        }

        public void startVideo() {
            int i = MyWallpaperService.this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            try {
                this.mCamera = Camera.open();
                if (this.mCamera != null) {
                    if (i == 1)
                        setDisplayOrientation(this.mCamera, 90);
                    if (i == 2)
                        setDisplayOrientation(this.mCamera, 0);
                    this.mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(this.hold);
                    this.mCamera.startPreview();
                }
                return;
            } catch (Exception localException) {
                while (true)
                    Log.e("MovieLiveWallpeperEngine", "Error : "
                            + localException.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void stopVideo() {
            if (this.mCamera != null) {
                this.mCamera.stopPreview();
                this.mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                this.mCamera.release();
                this.mCamera = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public class VideoSurfaceHolder implements SurfaceHolder {
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

        public VideoSurfaceHolder(SurfaceHolder arg2) {
            Object localObject = null;
            this.surfaceHolder = (SurfaceHolder) localObject;
        }

        public void addCallback(SurfaceHolder.Callback paramCallback) {
            this.surfaceHolder.addCallback(paramCallback);
        }

        public Surface getSurface() {
            return this.surfaceHolder.getSurface();
        }

        public Rect getSurfaceFrame() {
            return this.surfaceHolder.getSurfaceFrame();
        }

        public boolean isCreating() {
            return this.surfaceHolder.isCreating();
        }

        public Canvas lockCanvas() {
            return this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        }

        public Canvas lockCanvas(Rect paramRect) {
            return this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(paramRect);
        }

        public void removeCallback(SurfaceHolder.Callback paramCallback) {
            this.surfaceHolder.removeCallback(paramCallback);
        }

        public void setFixedSize(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
            this.surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(paramInt1, paramInt2);
        }

        public void setFormat(int paramInt) {
            this.surfaceHolder.setFormat(paramInt);
        }

        public void setKeepScreenOn(boolean paramBoolean) {
        }

        public void setSizeFromLayout() {
            this.surfaceHolder.setSizeFromLayout();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void setType(int paramInt) {
            this.surfaceHolder.setType(paramInt);
        }

        public void unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas paramCanvas) {
            this.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(paramCanvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Logcat error:

```
03-08 00:38:37.793: D/AndroidRuntime(20508): Shutting down VM
03-08 00:38:37.793: W/dalvikvm(20508): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4203e8b0)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at com.gordondev.copytransparent.MyWallpaperService$VideoSurfaceHolder.setType(MyWallpaperService.java:173)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at com.gordondev.copytransparent.MyWallpaperService$MovieLiveWallpeperEngine.onCreate(MyWallpaperService.java:45)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.attach(WallpaperService.java:777)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:1031)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:40)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
03-08 00:38:37.803: E/AndroidRuntime(20508):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 00:38:53.103: I/Process(20508): Sending signal. PID: 20508 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

//problem is you are making the localObject as null and you are assigning `null` to the `surfaceHolder`

```
public VideoSurfaceHolder(SurfaceHolder arg2) {
            Object localObject = null;
            this.surfaceHolder = (SurfaceHolder) localObject;
        }
```

//try assigning your `getSurfaceHolder` method to the `surfaceHolder`

```
 this.surfaceHolder = arg2;
```